# Numpy select lazy version

Tags: python, numpy, select, lazy-evaluation

Consider the code below

```
 >>> x = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
 >>> np.select([x==0, True], [x+1, 1/x])
 array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

It suffers from two problems.

Firstly, it is not lazy. It eagerly evaluates both x+1 and 1/x even though some of the evaluated values are not required in the final result.

Secondly, numpy issues a warning every time the code is run

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
```

which is somewhat related to the previous point, because it is trying to evaluate 1/x even when that is not required in the final answer.

Is there a version of select that is lazy and does not suffer from the problems above?

Comment: `np.select` doesn't evaluate `1/x`, python does.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use `y=x[:]; y[~x==0]=1/x[~x==0]; y[x==0]=x[x==0]+1`?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, I added it as answer.

Comment: @dzhelil I could finally do actual lazy evaluation. If you're interested, I updated my answer.

Comment: Consider taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52622392/6087087. That answer uses mask to do that.

Comment: @FıratKıyak so does mine ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid evaluation by explicitly masking your output vector for the two cases:

```
y = x.copy()
mask = (x == 0)  # parentheses only necessary for readability
y[mask] = x[mask] + 1
y[~mask] = 1 / x[~mask]
```

---

The above is what I strongly recommend doing, so you should only keep reading for a pointlessly contrived solution that actually tackles the "lazy evaluation" part of the question. I don't recommend using the below snippet in practice! You have been warned.

I could finally achieve actual lazy evaluation, although it's a bit messy and poses an unnecessary complication of the situation (well, at least this situation; I can imagine there are situations where this might come handy). In the spirit of "anything worth doing is worth overdoing":

```
xfun1 = [lambda xval=xval: xval + 1 for xval in x]
xfun2 = [lambda xval=xval: 1 / xval for xval in x]
[fun() for fun in np.select([x == 0, True], [xfun1, xfun2])]
```

The idea is to protect the values of `1/x` from being evaluated by hiding them behind `lambda` definitions. The auxiliary arrays `xfun1` and `xfun2` define a dummy `lambda` for each value of `x`; the first returning `x+1`, the second returning `1/x`. These, however, are not evaluated until you call an element as `xfun2[2]()`.

So we use the `select` call to choose elements from the two function arrays, but then we obtain a list of functions. In order to get numeric return values, we need to use a list comprehension to evaluate each `lambda`.

Comment: That is a great take on the problem. However, one of the objectives is to retain the efficiency of numpy, and be able to do it when say `x` has millions of elements. Your implementation relies on a list of python functions which would be quite slow.

Comment: @dzhelil indeed, that's why I said that it's an unnecessary complication. I only wanted to give a solution which adheres to the original specification;)

Comment: Thanks for the question and the answer. It gave me exactly what I was looking for, and the solution is great :)

Comment: @David I'm glad it's still useful after all these years! But I do hope you mean the first part of the answer :P

Comment: @Andras Deal I do, even though I found the second part very interesting :)