# Numpy "Where" function can not avoid evaluate Sqrt(negative)

Tags: python, numpy

It seems that the `np.where` function evaluates all the possible outcomes first, then it evaluates the condition later. This means that, in my case, it will evaluate square root of -5, -4, -3, -2, -1 even though it will not be used later on.

My code runs and works. But my problem is the warning. I avoided using a loop to evaluate each element, because it will run much slower than `np.where`.

So, here, I am asking

1. Is there any way to make `np.where` evaluate the condition first?
2. Can I turn off just this specific warning? How?
3. Another better way to do it if you have a better suggestion.

Here just a short example code corresponding my real code which is gigantic. But essentially has the same problem.

Input:

```
import numpy as np

c=np.arange(10)-5
d=np.where(c>=0, np.sqrt(c) ,c )
```

Output:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
d=np.where(c>=0,np.sqrt(c),c)
```

Comment: According to numpy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), the statement ```d=np.where(c>=0, np.sqrt(c) ,c )``` is equivalent to ```[sqcv if cond else cv for (cond, sqcv, cv) in zip(c>=0, np.sqrt(c), c)]```.
In other words, the term ```np.sqrt(c)``` is evaluated regardless of the condition ```c>=0```.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a *much* better way of doing this. Let's take a look at what your code is doing to see why.

`np.where` accepts three arrays as inputs. Arrays do not support lazy evaluation.

```
d = np.where(c >= 0, np.sqrt(c), c)
```

This line is therefore equivalent to doing

```
a = (c >= 0)
b = np.sqrt(c)
d = np.where(a, b, c)
```

Notice that the inputs are computed immediately, before `where` ever gets called.

Luckily, you don't need to use `where` at all. Instead, just use a boolean mask:

```
mask = (c >= 0)
d = np.empty_like(c)
d[mask] = np.sqrt(c[mask])
d[~mask] = c[~mask]
```

If you expect a lot of negatives, you can copy all the elements instead of just the negative ones:

```
d = c.copy()
d[mask] = np.sqrt(c[mask])
```

An even better solution might be to use masked arrays:

```
d = np.ma.masked_array(c, c < 0)
d = np.ma.sqrt(d)
```

To access the whole data array, with the masked portion unaltered, use `d.data`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. It works well. But when I try your last method. I still need the negative value. `d1=np.ma.masked_array(c.copy(), c<0)` and `d2=np.ma.masked_array(c.copy(), c>0)` . Then d=d1+d2. It do not work. Would you help help bit more?

Comment: I've added a note at the end

Comment: Using ufunc's `where` parameter directly is much more concise and usually faster. See answer by @hpaulj.

Comment: @Martin'Kvík'Baláž. I found out about that parameter after I wrote this. Definitely agree that it's the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

`np.sqrt` is a `ufunc` and accepts a `where` parameter.  It can be used as a mask in this case:

```
In [61]: c = np.arange(10)-5.0
In [62]: d = c.copy()
In [63]: np.sqrt(c, where=c>=0, out=d);
In [64]: d
Out[64]: 
array([-5.        , -4.        , -3.        , -2.        , -1.        ,
        0.        ,  1.        ,  1.41421356,  1.73205081,  2.        ])
```

In contrast to the `np.where` case, this does not evaluate the function at the ~where elements.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution in my opinion (also fastest, at least on my machine).

Answer (score 1):

This is answer to your 2nd question.

Yes you can turn off the warnings. Use [warnings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) module.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to not use `np.where`, and use indexing instead.

```
c = np.arange(10)-5
d = c.copy()
c_positive = c > 0
d[c_positive] = np.sqrt(c[c_positive])
```