# np.where element processing logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following code:

```
a = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
b = 1.999
val = a[abs(a-b)<0.01]
c = np.where(val.size!=0,val[0],0)
print(c)
```

The code runs without any issues when `val.size!=0` and gives the output `c = 2`. 
However when val.size evaluates to zero, for example,

```
a = np.asarray([1,3,4,5,6,7])
b = 1.999
val = a[abs(a-b)<0.01]
c = np.where(val.size!=0,val[0],0)
print(c)
```

I get the error: 
`IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` 
Why is it that `val.size=0` doesn't return 0 and instead try to process the value `val[0]`, that doesn't satisfy the condition ?

Comment: Since `c` is always a scalar why don't you just use `c = val[0] if val.size!=0 else 0` ?

Comment: Seems in np.where [all possible outcomes are always evaluated first regardless of conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622172/numpy-where-function-can-not-avoid-evaluate-sqrtnegative)

Comment: @FBruzzesi, Thank you for commenting. I wanted to try with np.where.

Comment: @DarrylG , Thank you for the link. It clears my doubt.

Comment: [Source](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html?highlight=where) For 1D arrays `numpy.where(condition[, x, y])` is equivalent to `[xv if c else yv
 for c, xv, yv in zip(condition, x, y)]` so we see that condition, x, y are evaluated always.